# Incorrect 2-stack algorithm (Java)

Tags: java, stack

I'm trying to write a program that evaluates mathematical expressions from elements in an arrayList. For example `["(", "3", "*", "2", ")"]` equates to the answer `6` since `(3*2)=6`.

I do this by pushing elements into two stacks: `operatorStack` and `valueStack`. The `operatorStack` takes in the brackets and operators while the `valueStack` only takes numbers.

My problem is when I have an arrayList as such `["(", "(", "3", "*", "3", ")", "*", "(", "5", "*", "2", ")", ")"]` which is the mathematical equivalent of `((3*3)*(5*2))`, the answer `10`, and not the expected `90`.

I'm not sure what where I've made the mistake in my stack pushing/popping.

```
   for(int i=0; i<tokenList.size(); i++) {
        String indexString = tokenList.get(i);
        //push to valueStack if num, else to operator Stack
        if (isInteger(indexString)) {
            valueStack.push(Integer.parseInt(indexString));
        } else {
            //if ) then calculate first

            if(indexString.equals(")")) {

                String opt = operatorStack.pop();

                while(!opt.equals("(")) {

                    int valB = valueStack.pop();
                    int valA = valueStack.pop();

                    //check operators:
                    if(opt.equals("++")) {
                        tmp = tmp + 1;
                    }
                    if(opt.equals("--")) {
                        tmp = tmp - 1;
                    }
                    if(opt.equals("+")) {
                        tmp = valA + valB;
                    } else if (opt.equals("-")) {
                        tmp = valA - valB;
                    } else if (opt.equals("*")) {
                        tmp = valA*valB;
                    } else if (opt.equals("/")) {
                        tmp = valA/valB;
                    }
                    valueStack.push(tmp);

                    opt = operatorStack.pop();
                    i++;
                }
            } else {
                operatorStack.push(indexString);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Throw it all away and look up recursive descent expression parsing or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm. You will never get there from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that problem in your i++ statement (inside while loop): you're just skipping next operator after closing bracket (multiplication sign in our case).Try to remove it.